# How to Determine which Graphic Card is in use (Win32)

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

For a bug reporting function in my 3ds max Plugin I want to display information about the video card (model, driver info etc.).

I've already found out that information about the graphic card can be achieved from the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}}\
```

Then there is a key for each graphic card beginning with `0000`.
On my notebook there are two such keys where the first one represents my on-board graphic card which can be ignored by my plugin.

How can I determine the name of the currently used graphics card?

Comment: And is it possible to use Win32 built-in methods like these (http://www.gamedev.net/topic/47021-how-to-determine-video-card-with-win32-api/)? If yes, this might be the solution.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @KarelBurda Yes it is possible, but unfortunately EnumDisplayDevices () does not provide the information which is the currently used card. I can only check which is the primary card and this is in fact the one which is on-board

Comment: @HansPassant Thx, I will check this function out soon

Comment: Remember that there might be more than one display adapter in use (on a multiple monitor setup, it's not necessary to have all monitors on a single card)

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished using DirectX 10+ as is documented [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

DirectX 10 is in included by default in Windows Vista, DirectX 11 is included in Windows7, and DirectX 11.1 is included with Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but I remembered that "WMI" might be the API that's relevent to that kind of query.

I googled for `wmi video card`: and found that maybe [the Win32_VideoController class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contains the information you want (but I don't know any more about it than that).